# Excel, Count Hour and Minute to Days More that 1 month

Tags: excel

I have a excel data with range date to be calculated

```
Created Time        Completed Time      Duration
07-Jan-2016 15:48   11-Jan-2016 15:39   3 Days 23:51
12-Jul-2016 11:28   28-Jul-2016 17:13   16 Days 05:45
12-Jul-2016 11:30   08-Nov-2016 10:40   118 Days 23:10
09/08/2016 14:45    31/08/2016 17:03    22 Days 02:18
09/08/2016 14:46    31/08/2016 17:04    22 Days 02:18
```

I have this formula below and the result on "duration" coloumn.
*CONCATENATE(TEXT(FLOOR(K4-J4;1);"@");" Days "; TEXT(K4-J4;"hH:mm"))*

I want to convert that counted days into months..
So it will be 3 Months, 28 Days 23 Hours and 10 Minutes for (118 Days 23:10)

Need your help to solve my problem :)

Comment: I vote for creating a column which contains the number of hours difference, and then reporting using this.

Answer (score 0):

**UNTESTED** Assuming `Created Time` is in A1, please try in C2 and copied down to suit:

```
=INT((B2-A2)/30)& " Months "&INT(MOD((B2-A2),30))&" Days "&INT(24*(MOD((B2-A2),30)-INT(MOD((B2-A2),30))))&" Hours and "&MINUTE(B2-A2)&" Minutes"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first Created Time is in A2 and the first Completed Time is in B2 then pop the following formula in C2 `=IF(DAYS(B2,A2)>0,CONCATENATE(IF(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y")=0,"",DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y")),IF(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y")=0,"", " year"),IF(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y")>1,"s",""),IF(AND(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y")>0,DATEDIF(A2,B2,"ym")>0),IF(IF(AND(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"md")>0,OR(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y")>0,DATEDIF(A2,B2,"ym")>0))," and ","")=""," and ",", "),""),IF(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"ym")=0,"",DATEDIF(A2,B2,"ym")),IF(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"ym")=0,"", " month"),IF(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"ym")>1,"s",""),IF(AND(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"md")>0,OR(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y")>0,DATEDIF(A2,B2,"ym")>0))," and ",""),IF(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"md")=0,"",DATEDIF(A2,B2,"md")),IF(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"md")=0,"", " day"),IF(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"md")>1,"s","")),"") & " " & HOUR(B2-A2) & " hours " & MINUTE(B2-A2) & " minutes"`